# vuejs timer component restart/stop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, countdown

i have to setup a 10 min timer which redirects to homescreen. Furthermore it have to reset on every action (e.g. button press). I found this timer: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/vue-countdown is it possible to restart it on a action?

```
<countdown ref="countdown" @end="dosmth()" :time="time" :auto-start="false">
<template slot-scope="props">{{ props.seconds }}</template>
</countdown>

mounted() {
    this.$refs.countdown.start();
  },


dosmth: function(){
          this.$refs.countdown.start();
        }
```

This should restart the timer but even this wont work:

Basket.vue:378
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "end": "InternalError: too much recursion"

Maybe someone can help me out?

Comment: nvm figured it out:
this.$refs.countdown.totalMilliseconds =  time;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `setInterval` and resetting the value to the initial value on each action click:

```js
const TEN_MINUTES = 60 * 10

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      timer: TEN_MINUTES
    }
  },
  filters: {
    minutesAndSeconds (value) {
      var minutes = Math.floor(parseInt(value, 10) / 60)
      var seconds = parseInt(value, 10) - minutes * 60
      return `${minutes}:${seconds}`
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.timer -= 1
    }, 1000)
  },
  methods: {
    someAction () {
      this.timer = TEN_MINUTES
    },
    someOtherAction () {
      this.timer = TEN_MINUTES
    }
  },
  template: `<div><div>Time Remaining: {{ timer | minutesAndSeconds }}</div><br><br><button @click="someAction">Some Action</button><button @click="someOtherAction">Some Other Action</button></div>`
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much